# How do you detemine if a polymorph form can use a weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons, wild-shape, polymorph

I am playing a druid who is going to be wild shaping. How do I determine if a weapon can be used in a particular form? Some forms are obvious like a chicken can't pick up and use a sword.

Other forms are less clear. For example, what about an [octopus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/octopus/)? It has 8 tentacles/legs and it can grab things, but could it use a sword or a bow? How do you determine if a given form can use a weapon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The rules are not clear

While it is known that [all your carried gear melds into your body while polymorphed](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Transmutation-Polymorph), what happens if you drop your weapon as a *free action* and then picks it up **is left at GM discretion**.

Most polymorphed creatures are not physically able to hold weapons or operate mechanisms, so we have to use some logic thinking to decide if a certain form could operate a bow or a greatsword with her limbs. Which leads us to *table variation* and things like [sword-wielding crabs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ebsvoRqPOMk).

However, the [Animal Archive](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8w7p?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Animal-Archive) player companion has something to say about primates wielding weapons whenever they are [awakened](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/awaken/), as in, they have the intelligence to wield them properly:

> The weapons primates wield also run the gamut. A gorilla might choose an enormous club, a chimpanzee a two-handed sword that lets him take advantage of his tremendous strength, and a monkey a hand crossbow or blunderbuss.

When asked if a [druid polymorphed into primate could pick up and use manufactured weapons](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=575?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#28742), [James Jacobs](http://paizo.com/people/JamesJacobs) (Paizo's Creative Director) said:

> **That's 100% a GM call**. I would allow it with no penalty, mostly because I've read enough Conan stories to think a gorilla with a scimitar is cool looking.

Comment: The video of the crab was great. My brother's dog also managed to get a knife once and was holding it in its mouth.

Answer (score 1):

**Wild shape druids cannot use weapons**

For starters, animals won't have the required proficiency feats to use weapons or the INT score to learn these feats in the first place.

Additionally, according to [Paizo](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5lc1y?Monkey-See-Monkey-Do-An-FAQ-on-Intelligent):

> There are a number of feats that convey an understanding and the proper use of weapons and armor. Generally speaking, these feats are off-limits to animals, but when their intelligence reaches 3, the rules state that they can use any feat that they are physically capable of using. Some people take this to mean that they can equip their animal companion in chainmail and arm him with a greatsword given the correct feats. While you could interpret the rules in this way, the "capable of use" clause is very important. **Most weapons require thumbs to use properly,** and even then, few animals would choose to use an artificial weapon in place of the natural weapons that have served them all their life. It's what they were born with, after all, and virtually no amount of training will change that.

The article focuses on animal companions but this also applies to beast/wild shape.

PS: In case of GM fiat allowing some forms (such as an Ape) to wield weapons: According to [this entry on magic](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magic.html), your gear (in its entirety, not only what you're holding on your person) is melded away when you use wildshape, requiring your Druid to pick up a weapon elsewhere after transforming;

Comment: A druid in animal form doesn't see his Intelligence score reduced to that of the animal's, though. The lack of thumbs is a bummer for some shapes, but a damn dirty ape with human smarts should—because the form has thumbs—be able to manage a sword or even maybe a bow. The problem is determining *which forms* have thumbs! (And, of course, if tentacles can be used to wield weapons.)

Comment: The creature still, explicity, requires the necessary Proficiency feat to wield a weapon effectively. It may sound silly that a gorilla can't just pick up a club and smack a goblin in the face but it's RAW. Weapon proficiency comes with character class and is not inherited by wild shaping.

Comment: But *a druid in animal form* doesn't *lose* his druid weapon proficiencies. Of course, like, an awakened ape with only its racial Hit Dice lacks proficiency with all but its natural weapons, but it could still pick up a club and use that club, suffering the penalties for nonproficiency.

Comment: I see you're addressing animal forms, but most druids can turn into elemental forms via Wild Shape.  Any comment on humanoid elemental forms?

Comment: @Cellion My main route is to be using the elemental forms because huge air elemental gets both flying and size. I was just wondering if there was a way to wield two or more bows.